# Can't style content of an element (content::content) in Safari, works fine in Chrome

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer

See http://mycommunity.org in both Chrome and Safari. (This is post-dart2js.)

Click the create button top right, note how the elements in the dialog are styled in Chrome but *not* in Safari.

In Safari I can't get the stuff styled!

This is what's working in Chrome:

```
content::content h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  color: #334C80;
}
```

It's not working in Safari, even when I do things like:

```
core-overlay::content h1 {
  color: orange;
}
```

This is how it lives in the code ([link](https://github.com/DaveNotik/dart-stack/blob/82d7dca4651016ee0ee69d73d0ac5f4432a70f01/lib/components/widgets/dialog/dialog.html#L22)):

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../../../../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../../../../../packages/core_elements/core_overlay.html">
<polymer-element name="x-dialog">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dialog.css">
    <core-overlay id="overlay" layered backdrop opened="{{opened}}" autoCloseDisabled="{{autoCloseDisabled}}"  transition="core-transition-center">
      <content></content>
    </core-overlay>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="dialog.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: See the `polyfill-*` selectors: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#directives

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ebidel. The answer was indeed:

```
polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host h1'; }
::content h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html#directives

I think the docs could be simpler a la "when you want to do X, use Y". I didn't know I wanted polyfill-* selectors even after reading through the styling guide.